# Laravel Subdomain and Valet

Tags: php, laravel

I have a site that will have a forward facing public version and an auth user side. I am trying to test it locally so I have anything at the root domain point to one view and the subdomain point to another view. The trouble is they both point to the `welcome` view.

web routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::domain('pro.scorecard.dev')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('app.dashboard');
    });

});
```

I also ran:

`valet link pro.scorecard`

But if I go to `pro.scorecard.dev` or `scorecard.dev` they both show the view `welcome.blade.php`

Comment: What's the Laravel version you are working on?

Comment: It’s a fresh install so should be 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the routes as :

```
Route::domain('pro.scorecard.dev')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('app.dashboard');
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Cant believe I didnt try that. Thanks!

Comment: Just to verify this answer. Laravel added this to the documentation: "In order to ensure your subdomain routes are reachable, you should register subdomain routes before registering root domain routes. This will prevent root domain routes from overwriting subdomain routes which have the same URI path."